# WUBI Installation Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 on ACER Windows 10 Home - Windows failed to start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, wubi

I'm trying to install a Ubuntu dual boot on my ACER Windows 10 Home laptop by following this documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi.

When it reboots I have this error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."
    
If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubnldr.mbr  

  Status: 0xc0000007b  

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required   
        file is missing or contains errors.
```

After press Enter, I can choose Windows 10 or Ubuntu. If I choose Ubuntu I have this error, but Windows 10 can still start properly.

I have read a couple of issues like this, I have disabled the fast UEFI boot, but I'm still having this issue.

Comment: **Wubi requires Windows 98, ME, 2000, XP, Vista, Windows 7** WUBI isn't used for more than 10 years because it doesn't support UEFI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score -1):

I finally get rid of it by installing Ubuntu from USB, then enable F12 boot.